# How to use excel to separate text with comma and space

Tags: excel

I have some text in cells with format like `Clare, South Australia 5453`. And `Red Bluff, California 96080`
The order is `city`, `state` and `zip code`.

Now i would like to use excel to separate this text into three parts, like `Clare`, `South Australia` and `5453` in different cells using excel.

Hope some one could give me a hint. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ToomanyAlex `Clare, South Australia 5453` is text and i need to separate this into three parts

Comment: Maybe you take a look on Text To Columns: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7 first

Comment: @ToomanyAlex Thanks. I will take a look :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it in one step, I would recommend writing a macro for this. 
If you have the possibility to do it in 2 steps, you can use the Text-To-Columns feature in the Data tab and a formula.

First, you could split the text into columns at the comma, thus you get Clare and South Austria 5453 in two separate columns.

Then you could go to into the cell containing the state and the zip code, and use a formula to find the first numeric value:

```
=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))
```

(For more details see: https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-and-numbers)

This solution of course, does not work in place. If you would like to do the splitting without helper columns, I would recommend writing a short macro to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new macro using the code below.  You use it by ensuring the current cell (ie the ActiveCell) is on one of the text cells you want to convert.  You then execute the macro and it should place the 3 items in adjacent cells (which I'm assuming are empty).

The macro uses a regular expression (as defined by 'strPattern') which will pick up however many sets of characters separated by blanks prior to the comma.  It will do the same after the comma and then match the zip code separately.

```
Public Sub simpleRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^\s*((\w+\s*){1,}),\s*((\w+\s*){1,})\s+(\d+)"
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    strInput = ActiveCell.Value

    With regEx
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = True
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
       Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = matches(0).submatches(0)
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = matches(0).submatches(2)
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = matches(0).submatches(4)
    Else
       MsgBox ("Not matched")
    End If
End Sub
```

Caveat here is that you might have to play with it for all the string variations you might encounter.  It does work on the two examples you provided.